# Using Javascript variable with {{Click Text}} variable to tracking a href tag text

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

with GTM, i tried to track which ' tags' are clicked by users. 
i created custom javascript variable which contains some conditions to track each 'a tags'. but it didn't work.

what is problem? i checked the grammars or typo but seems no problem. T_T

Those 'a tags' have no image alt value, no id, no class name, but only url and text. So i tried to track those tags with Custom Javascript Variables with built-in variables {{Click text}}, but failed.

In GTM preview mode, this Custom Javascript Variables results in 'undefined'.

belows are my codes.

Custom Javascript variable

```
function() {
var result = '';
var clickText = {{Click Text}}
if (clickText.indexOf('getCoupon') > -1) {
    result = 'getCoupon';
  } else if (clickText.indexOf('getCoupon2') > -1) {
    result = 'getCoupon2';
  }
    return result;
}
```

※ built-in variable {{Click Text}} returns string value 'getCoupon' or 'getCoupon2'

Answer (score 0):

What trigger are you using for the tag where you use that variable js?

Comment: i use click-link trigger which is triggered by click element(defined with CSS selector).